# Linker error when adding frameworks to native worklight project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are using Worklight Developer Edition v6.0 with XCode v5.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.

Newly built Worklight hybrid apps works fine on the iOS 7 devices running from XCode, but when we add a new native framework into XCode, it results in a Linker error related to Worklight libraries during builds (image below). I've tried this with multiple frameworks that worked fine with my previous version of Worklight 5.0.5. Please advise.

[image: linker error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're facing same xcode problem I've recently faced. Once I'm adding new frameworks/libraries xcode breaks framework search path by adding extra slashes.

In your project properties to go Build Settings and look for Framework Search Path. It should have several entries, one of them is $(SRCROOT)/Frameworks. Make sure that after you add your framework this entry remains unchanged. In my case xcode added several extra quotes and slashes making framework files unreachable.

Comment: Thanks Anton! Whenever I add a new third party framework, the Library Search Path in build settings had these extra slashes for the WorklightSDK and TeaLeaf entries. After I removed the extra slashes, it worked fine.